# Django join like queries

Tags: django, join

I have two models

```
class A(models.Model):
  id = PGUUIDField(primary_key=True)
  name = CharField(max_length=32)
  prefix = CharField(max_length=64)
  controller = models.ForeignKey(Controller)
  location = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="blink")

class B(models.Model):
  id = PGUUIDField(primary_key=True)
  name = CharField(max_length=128)
```

The table for A contains many A objects and the table for B contains many B objects.

Using raw sql I can...

```
SELECT b.* FROM B AS b
JOIN A AS a
ON b.id = a.location_id
```

And I get a list of All B objects that A has a foreign key to.

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this with pure Django.
Can you please tell me how?

I have looked up select_related and tried it but I must be doing something wrong. I keep getting a queryset of A objects

Currently using the following:

```
queryset2 = []
    try:
        qs = A.objects.all().values('location_id')
        queryset2 = B.objects.filter(id__in=qs)
        print queryset2
        self.fields['location'].queryset = queryset2
```

Comment: This is covered in [Part 2 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/).

Comment: queryset2 = B.objects.filter(id=a__location_id)    --returns --global name 'a__location_id' is not defined (<type 'exceptions.NameError'>)<br>I assume you were reffering to this "Choice.objects.filter(question__pub_date__year=current_year)" in the tutorial

Comment: No, I am not referring to that. You're also not doing what they're doing in the tutorial. Notice the double underscore syntax is for the _name of the argument_, not the argument itself. That's why you're getting a name error, because you're referencing a variable named `a__location_id` that you never defined.

Comment: Well which part are you referring to?   and in the tutorial "question__pub_date__year" question is the model name and pub_date is the column. How is that different from a__location_id? a is the model name and location_id is the column

Comment: I'm not going to read the tutorial for you. It's different for exactly the reason I said -- theirs is the name of the argument and yours is the value. `B.objects.filter(name=value)`. You can use that syntax as the name, but not as the value.

Comment: Dude, I just obviously don't understand.  "question__pub_date" is the name of an argument? Or are you referring to the full "question__pub_date__year" and __year is the argument?

Comment: I'm not sure how to say it. :/ It goes on the other side of the `=` in the filter expression. `Choice.objects.filter(question__pub_date__year=current_year)` is OK. `Choice.objects.filter(current_year=question__pub_date__year)` will only work if `current_year` is a real field on `Choice` model (it's not) and `question__pub_date__year` is a real variable defined in current scope (it's not).

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't realize you were talking about order of the fields. That makes total sense. My mind is kind of all over the place today.

Comment: And I'm sorry for assuming at first you might be a help vampire. You don't seem to be. Chalk it up to bad experiences answering questions sometimes. Good luck with Django.

Comment: Lol, I like that term "help vampire". No, I am fairly new to the industry and at my job I code in many languages, a lot of them are pretty new to me.  There are only 2 developers, me being one. So sometimes I may be focused on something else, but have to tweak something over there but my brain didn't switch tracks yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're at reading up on the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/), this should what you want:

```
B.objects.prefetch_related('blink').all()
```

More on [writing queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: This keeps returning a list of all the B objects. Not just the ones that A has a foreign key to

Comment: Each of the `B` objects has associated `A` objects that can be accessed by `b.blink`

Comment: Thank you, but I must ask one more thing.  How do I get the queryset of only the related items?

Comment: Only the related items? Then you may want to query directly on A. If `ids` are ids of B objects, then `A.objects.filter(location_id__in=ids)` will return all As that match the query. Or you may consider using [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values) which does not return model objects but selected values.

Comment: Thank you! That works well.  I ended up generating a list of all the B.location_id and passed that in as "ids"